# Syntax error when inserting data into SQL database from a novice

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create an SQL database table and insert some data ("mask_id" below). I am receiving the error `sqlite3.OperationalError near ")"`: syntax error that is referring to the last line (row['MASKID'],)). Specifically, I am trying to read a CSV file and insert data from the 'MASKID' column into my database.

I am unable to troubleshoot and would appreciate some help.

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subj_list (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, mask_id TEXT)''')

with open('/Users/Leo/Desktop/bp.csv', 'rU') as bp_csv:
    bp_reader = csv.DictReader(bp_csv)
    count = 0
    for row in bp_reader:
        cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO subj_list (mask_id,) VALUES (?,)' (row['MASKID'],))
```

Comment: `cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO subj_list (mask_id) VALUES (?)' , (row['MASKID'],))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a comma:

```
cur.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO subj_list (mask_id) VALUES (?)',
     (row['MASKID'],))
```